# House prices: Advanced regression techniques, Feature importance and Plot barplot of top 5 Feature Importances

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am working on a project where I need to plot barplot of top 5 Feature Importances, using a data set of House prices: Advanced regression techniques, I have calculated the RandomForest Regressor using :

```
RF_model = RandomForestRegressor() 
  RF_model.fit(x,y)
  RF_model.score(x,y)
pred=RF_model.predict(df_test)
output=pd.DataFrame({'Id':Id, 'SalePrice':pred})
output.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
output.head(5)
```

and have also calculated the feature importance using the following code

```
feature = pd.DataFrame(df_train.drop(['SalePrice', 'Id'], axis=1).columns, RF_model.feature_importances_)
```

Now I am plotting the barplot of top 5 feature using below code

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
fig = sns.barplot(data = feature.sort_values(by = 'Coeff', ascending=False)[:5], x= 'Feature', y='Coeff')
plt.show();
```

### but it is giving me the following error

> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 1 f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
> ----> 2 fig = sns.barplot(data = feature.sort_values(by = 'Coeff', ascending=False)[:5], x= 'Feature', y='Coeff')
> 3 plt.show();
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in
> sort_values(self, by, axis, ascending, inplace, kind, na_position,
> ignore_index)    4925     4926             by = by[0]
> -> 4927             k = self._get_label_or_level_values(by, axis=axis)    4928     4929             if isinstance(ascending, (tuple, list)):
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in
> _get_label_or_level_values(self, key, axis)    1690             values = self.axes[axis].get_level_values(key)._values    1691         else:
> -> 1692             raise KeyError(key)    1693     1694         # Check for duplicates
>
> KeyError: 'Coeff'

Can someone please help me in fixing the issue? Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the `feature_importances_` attribute of your trained model with `RF_model.feature_importances_`. Then you can plot them as needed. Check out the [`sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor` documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html) for more details and additional attributes/methods you can use to access your model.

Comment: can you please suggest the final code, that would plot the bar chart

Comment: I can give it a shot if you can provide a link to the dataset you used and the remainder of the code you used (e.g. your data cleaning, train-test-split, package imports, etc.).

Comment: Thanks so much! files are available in the notebook folder, along with the data here https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/18NjuJOyY-9hfOMLdTjXFEAtp2PGWac-8?usp=sharing